# Transit visa for Japan

Tags: japan

I have booked my ticket from Canada to India via Haneda airport, Japan. My layover is 16 hours at Haneda airport and date change 10 July to 11 July. Is a transit visa required?

Comment: Are you a Canadian or Indian national?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Embassy of Japan in Canada](https://www.ca.emb-japan.go.jp/itpr_en/transit_visa.html),

A transit Visa is for travelers who are stopping over in Japan en route to another country due to flight schedules.

- Canadian citizens and nationals of countries with Reciprocal Visa
  Exemption Agreements with Japan do not require a Transit Visa. ([List
  of the countries](https://www.mofa.go.jp/j_info/visit/visa/short/novisa.html#list)) As of March 16 2023, Canada is on the Reciprocal Visa Exemption Agreements list. India is not.
- No visa required for all nationalities if you are
  transiting through Japan within the same airport without leaving the
  secured area.

This information allows us to answer your question:

1. If you do not need to leave the secured area of your arrival airport to take your connecting flight, you do not need a transit Visa.
2. If you need to leave the secured area, you do no need a transit visa if the passport you use to travel is on the Reciprocal Visa Exemption Agreements list. If your nationality is not on the list, you need a transit visa.

Some reasons you could have to leave the secured area are:

- Change of airport for connecting flight.
- Change of airport terminal.
- Layover too long to stay in the secured area (not all airport terminals are 24h).